# Optimizing a T-SQL query with COUNT in the SELECT and HAVING statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, optimization

I am not sure if this is to do with the fact that I am dealing with very large tables (some have 900+ million rows) but I am having trouble optimizing my query. I have also checked and used indexed fields wherever possible , with most of the fields being used on my query actually being indexed.Using a `select top 100` statement takes roughly 10 minutes and i would like to get all of the results back, much more faster. How would I go about for optimizing this query and future queries like it? For security purposes I had to use alternative aliases below:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    x.ID, j.ID, j.FirstDate, j.ExpiryDate, x.Lock, COUNT (*) as Numbers
FROM
   j WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN   
   jp WITH(NOLOCK) ON j.ID = jp.ID
INNER JOIN   
   jd WITH(NOLOCK) ON (jd.ID = jp.ID And jd.path = 3)
INNER JOIN  
   fa WITH(NOLOCK) ON fa.ID = j.ID
INNER JOIN  
   l WITH(NOLOCK) ON j.ID = l.ID AND l.CoID = 3
INNER JOIN   
   c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.CID = fa.CID
INNER JOIN  
   x WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.CID = x.CID
WHERE  
   j.ExpiryDate > GETDATE()
GROUP BY 
   x.ID, j.ID, j.FirstDate, j.ExpiryDate, x.Lock
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) <= 10
```

Comment: Set [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is ***NOT RECOMMENDED*** to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Press that button for the explain plan and attach it here

Comment: If it weren't for `getdate()`, I'd say materialized view would be worth a look.

Comment: Removing WITH(NOLOCK) didnt have any difference, but the link was an interesting read.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    x.ID, j.ID, j.FirstDate, j.ExpiryDate, x.Lock, COUNT (*) as Numbers
FROM
   j WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN   
   jp WITH(NOLOCK) ON j.ID = jp.ID 
                  and j.ExpiryDate > GETDATE()
INNER JOIN   
   jd WITH(NOLOCK) ON (jd.ID = jp.ID And jd.path = 3)
INNER JOIN  
   fa WITH(NOLOCK) ON fa.ID = j.ID
INNER JOIN  
   l WITH(NOLOCK) ON j.ID = l.ID AND l.CoID = 3
INNER JOIN   
   c WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.CID = fa.CID
INNER JOIN  
   x WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.CID = x.CID      
GROUP BY 
   x.ID, j.ID, j.FirstDate, j.ExpiryDate, x.Lock
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) <= 10
```

Comment: I see a lot of this behavior, i dont get why people hop on to a question just down vote everyone else.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it helps to reduce the data set ina derived table and then apply the function only on the data that meets the where condition. Without seeing axecution plans for both, I don;t know itf this will work, but iti si worth a tr.

```
SELECT  a.XID, a.JID, a.FirstDate, a.ExpiryDate, a.Lock, COUNT (*) as Numbers
FROM (
SELECT 
    x.ID as XID, j.ID as JID, j.FirstDate, j.ExpiryDate, x.Lock
FROM
   j 
INNER JOIN   
   jp  ON j.ID = jp.ID
INNER JOIN   
   jd  ON (jd.ID = jp.ID And jd.path = 3)
INNER JOIN  
   fa  ON fa.ID = j.ID
INNER JOIN  
   l ON j.ID = l.ID AND l.CoID = 3
INNER JOIN   
   c  ON c.CID = fa.CID
INNER JOIN  
   x ON c.CID = x.CID
WHERE  
   j.ExpiryDate > GETDATE()) a
GROUP BY 
  a.XID, a.JID, a.FirstDate, a.ExpiryDate, a.Lock
HAVING 
   COUNT(*) <= 10
```